# App is crashing after integrating with Mopub

Tags: android, mopub

We have integrated with Mopub for ad integration.
The app is working fine with `minify = false`.
But, with `minify = true`, the app is crashing. We have added all the proguard rules in out file mentioned in this link : https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/mopub-sample/proguard.cfg.

Log :

```
    03-12 17:00:04.791 16874-16874/in.playsimple.word_up I/Tapjoy: The session ended
03-12 17:00:05.140 16874-17001/in.playsimple.word_up E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8523b20
03-12 17:00:05.211 16874-16874/in.playsimple.word_up E/ActivityThread: Activity org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.mopub.mobileads.au@dca7bd8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                       android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.mopub.mobileads.au@dca7bd8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:918)
                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:719)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1172)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1152)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1146)
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:554)
                                                                           at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.a(MoPubView.java:110)
                                                                           at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.<init>(MoPubView.java:88)
                                                                           at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.<init>(MoPubView.java:54)
                                                                           at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial$MoPubInterstitialView.<init>(MoPubInterstitial.java:397)
                                                                           at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial.<init>(MoPubInterstitial.java:71)
                                                                           at in.playsimple.word_up.Interstitial$2.run(Interstitial.java:116)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-12 17:00:05.217 16874-16925/in.playsimple.word_up D/WordTrek: pingworking = true
03-12 17:00:05.217 16874-16925/in.playsimple.word_up D/WordTrek: Downloading file :: https://playsimple.co/misc_web_server/wordtrek/dictionary_eowl.csv.gz
03-12 17:00:05.218 16874-16925/in.playsimple.word_up I/WordTrek: Downloading file = dictionary_eowl.csv.gz
03-12 17:00:05.218 16874-16925/in.playsimple.word_up D/WordTrek: pingworking = true
03-12 17:00:05.235 16874-16874/in.playsimple.word_up E/ActivityThread: Activity org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@df3ec64 that was originally bound here
                                                                       android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@df3ec64 that was originally bound here
                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1092)
                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:986)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1303)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
                                                                           at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.connectToEngine(TextToSpeech.java:800)
                                                                           at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:770)
                                                                           at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:723)
                                                                           at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:702)
                                                                           at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:686)
                                                                           at org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity.initTextToSpeech_aroundBody10(AppActivity.java:709)
                                                                           at org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity$AjcClosure11.run(AppActivity.java:1)
                                                                           at org.a.b.b.c.c(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
                                                                           at c.a.a.a.a(Hugo.java:39)
                                                                           at org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity.initTextToSpeech(AppActivity.java:709)
                                                                           at org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity.setup_aroundBody8(AppActivity.java:701)
                                                                           at org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity$AjcClosure9.run(AppActivity.java:1)
                                                                           at org.a.b.b.c.c(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
                                                                           at c.a.a.a.a(Hugo.java:39)
                                                                           at org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity.setup(AppActivity.java:619)
                                                                           at org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity.onCreate_aroundBody0(AppActivity.java:178)
                                                                           at org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity$AjcClosure1.run(AppActivity.java:1)
                                                                           at org.a.b.b.c.c(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
                                                                           at c.a.a.a.a(Hugo.java:39)
                                                                           at org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity.onCreate(AppActivity.java:146)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-12 17:00:06.235 16874-17523/in.playsimple.word_up I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16874 SIG: 9
```

:

Comment: Check your receiver code logic. has it been properly unregistered

Answer (score 0):

Add below rule to your proguard file:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBannerAdapter {!private !public !protected *;}
```

Comment: Does it fixed your issue or still facing the same issue ?